# Jquery addClass based on relative URL

Tags: jquery

I have a problem about *addClass* to *div* based on relative url.

this is my code

```
<div id="top"></div>

if (window.location.href == "product.php?p=blablabla") {
    $("#top").addClass(".topscroll");   
}
else { }

.topscro {background:red; }
```

blablabla is relative url that can change based on `PHP $_GET`,

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: The only thing wrong with your code is that you are abusing the operator `==` . it is supposed to match exactly, not partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check for equality as it will have the complete url of the page instead check whether `href` contains the pattern

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("product.php?p=blablabla") > -1) {
    $("#top").addClass(".topscroll");
}
```